# Internet Explorer Trigger File download via javascript with CSRF Header using POST

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, iframe, http-headers, csrf

I have a web application that was working just fine until someone implemented a CSRF fix on our server.  Now we can't call POST requests without including a particular header in our http request.  This broke a file download that requires a POST request to fetch the data instead of using the GET url parameters.

I have a fix that does an ajax POST request (with post data) using the new X-CSRF header.  This works, and it returns the correct content-disposition response header.  The problem is that you can't get the browser to open a "Save As" dialog, or auto download.

In chrome/firefox, I did a hack where you add a dummy Anchor tag with a data URI and click it:

Internet explorer doesn't like data URIs or clicking this href with javascript.
I can't use flash as an option because the customer wants the product to work with flash.

Iframes don't work because you can't send custom http headers with Iframes.

You can add Jquery to a form that POSTs to the url, but it doesn't trigger the "Save As" or download browser interaction.

Is there any solution that actually works with IE 9 or 10?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so this works in IE10
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh779016(v=vs.85).aspx

Assuming you setup an XHR with arraybuffer response type

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST", "/lamo_api", true);
xhr.responseType = "arraybuffer";
xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF', getCSRFToken()); // getCSRFToken() returns a string
xhr.onload = function() {
  var blob_builder = window.MSBlobBuilder();
  builder.append(xhr.response);
  var blob = new Blob(buffer, {'type': mimeType || 'application/octet-stream'});
  window.navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, filename);
};
xhr.send(xml_post_data);
```

Still looking for a IE9 answer...